# Should my gutter/margins expand in a fluid design?

Tags: layout

I'm redesigning a page, and am going for a fairly basic fluid, 2-column layout. With a fluid layout though, should I have my gutter and margins expand along with the columns, or would it be better to keep them a static size regardless of how the user resizes their browser?

I'm applying the [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) to the column width so I would like to apply it also to the  gutter/margins but I don't really see how that could be done without them being HUGE (or at least huge for gutters. If they're static size it's a moot point of course.

Comment: When you say "Fluid 2," are you referring to this layout?
http://pixelunion.net/themes/fluid2/

Comment: I think he just meant "fluid, 2-column layout"?

Comment: Also, what margin are you referring to?  Between the columns and the outer edge of the page?

Comment: What a difference a comma or hyphen can make.

Comment: @Evan: I just left out the comma.

Comment: @peteorpeter: Gutter=space between the two columns. Margins=space between columns and edges of pages.

Comment: see also my answer to similar query on graphic design: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/golden-ratio-with-or-without-padding-margin/2576#2576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a hard-and-fast rule (or "best practice"), but, shooting from the hip, **I don't think you should expand the gutter**.

The general pattern in the wild is that you have discrete elastic sections that expand, and everything else maintains it's relative position.  I can't seem to find a live example on the web in my quick searching (though [Ethan Marcotte's seminal ALA breakdown of fluid grids](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/) does a little of it at extremely small window size). Amazon.com, Gmail, and Google News all maintain consistent margin/gutter spacing as they stretch.

"Everybody else does it" is not necessarily a reason to follow suit, but, instinctively, this feels a little more stable and consistent to users - there are less moving parts than if *every* element changes dimension.  It's a little more self-explanatory of the mechanism, perhaps?  Also, it looks less like actual browser zooming.

You could make a case for expanding them *ever-so-slightly* as the page width increases - certainly not in direct proportion with the width - but I doubt that subtle effect is worth the additional complexity.